# how to enable “autoscroll” in kendo timepicker at selected value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I've a kendo TimePicker for showning time when I change time and open timepicker control it scroll down to selected time but when i set value at time of page load 
and I open timepicker control it does not scroll down to the set time.

Is there any way so that it should sroll down to the set time ?

Tx.

Comment: What times are you entering/setting?  The TimePicker seems to be able to scroll to the time regardless of how the time was set when the value is actually present in the dropdown, i.e. "9:00 AM" works(whether entered at runtime or set at page load) but "9:05 AM" does not because "9:05 AM" is not a value in the dropdown and thus cannot be selected.  Is this what you are seeing?

Comment: I have kendo timepicker control which is containing time in 5 min interval i.e. "9:00 AM, 9:05 AM, 9:10 AM".  If I select any time from dropdown and close the dropdown and once I reopen the dropdown it took me the selected time.   But when I set the value in TimePicker dropdown i.e "10:35 PM" and when I open the dropdown it should scroll down to the "10:35 PM" which is not happening right now.

Did you get my point of issue ?

Comment: Can you provide a non-working example in the Kendo Dojo?  You can use this as a starting point: http://dojo.telerik.com/@Stephen/AhORE.  I can only reproduce the issue if the time value is not in the dropdown, which makes sense as you cannot select something that does not exist, i.e. "9:02 AM" in a list that has 5 minute intervals.